# Pointing to Google that a specific website is for mobiles

Tags: seo, google, google-search, robots.txt, mobile

I have 2 websites: let's call them A and B.

- A is a Desktop optimized website.
- B is a mobile version of A, but it's not on the same domain. It also has a smaller amount of content/pages than A

**How do I tell Google**, and other search engines, that I would prefer to have only mobile users on B (no desktop users) and **that B is a mobile version of A**.

I already have user agent detection and BIG BIG messages inviting users to switch platforms when convenient for them, but I want Google to send them directly to the appropriate site.

I use Google Analytics and Webmaster tools on both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, there is no method to do this currently. Google results on mobile are largely the same as on desktop.

However, Google has a special mobile user agent, `Googlebot-Mobile`, so you could detect this (if you don't already) and make sure there is a link to the mobile version.

I've also seen a few sources that list this meta tag, but I don't know if it's actually used by any search engines:

```
<link rel="alternate" media="handheld" href="mobile-version.html">
```

Comment: Here's the video from Matt Cutts: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mY9h3G8Lv4k

Comment: Yep. In essence all you need to do is treat Googlebot-Mobile as if it's any other mobile user. So if you currently redirect iPhone users to the mobile version then redirect Googlebot-Mobile. If you just display a link to the mobile version, do the same for Googlebot-Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Google's tips on Mobile Sites for Webmasters:

- [Making Websites Mobile Friendly](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/02/making-websites-mobile-friendly.html)
- [Where can I find information on developing my own mobile sites?](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=72462)
- [Help Google index your mobile site](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/11/help-google-index-your-mobile-site.html)